# Python - Zip code to Barcode

Tags: python, python-2.7

The code is supposed to take a 5 digit zip code input and convert it to bar codes as the output. The bar code for each digit is:

```
{1:'...!!',2:'..!.!',3:'..!!.',4:'.!..!',5:'.!.!.',6:'.!!..',7:'!...!',8:'!..!.',9:'!.!..',0:'!!...'}
```

For example, the zip code 95014 is supposed to produce:

```
!!.!.. .!.!. !!... ...!! .!..! ...!!!
```

There is an extra `!` at the start and end, that is used to determine where the bar code starts and stops. Notice that at the end of the bar code is an extra `...!!` which is an 1. This is the check digit and you get the check digit by:

- Adding up all the digits in the zipcode to make the sum *Z*
- Choosing the check digit *C* so that Z + C is a multiple of 10

For example, the zipcode `95014` has a sum of *Z* = 9 + 5 + 0 + 1 + 4 = 19, so the check digit *C* is 1 to make the total sum *Z* + *C* equal to 20, which is a multiple of 10.

```
def printDigit(digit):
    digit_dict = {1:'...!!',2:'..!.!',3:'..!!.',4:'.!..!',5:'.!.!.',6:'.!!..',7:'!...!',8:'!..!.',9:'!.!..',0:'!!...'}
    return digit_dict[digit]

def printBarCode(zip_code):
    sum_digits=0
    num=zip_code
    while num!=0:
        sum_digits+=(num%10)
        num/=10
    rem = 20-(sum_digits%20)
    answer=[]
    for i in str(zip_code):
        answer.append(printDigit(int(i)))
    final='!'+' '.join(answer)+'!'
    return final

print printBarCode(95014)
```

The code I currently have produces an output of

`!!.!.. .!.!. !!... ...!! .!..!!`

for the zip code `95014` which is missing the check digit. Is there something missing in my code that is causing the code not to output the check digit? Also, what to include in my code to have it ask the user for the zip code input?

Comment: You literally have the check digit algorithm right there. What problem are you having in coding it? Also, have you searched for "python ask user for input"?

Comment: I know I have it but it's not working...

Comment: You're calculating `rem` and never using it.

Comment: Where would I include that?

Comment: It is given in your problem statement.

Comment: Let me re-phase my question: Where would I put it in my code in order to use it and have it print it out? I am sorry I am asking beginner's questions because yes, I am new to Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code computes `rem` based on the sum of the digits, but you never use it to add the check-digit bars to the output (`answer` and `final`). You need to add code to do that in order to get the right answer. I suspect you're also not computing `rem` correctly, since you're using `%20` rather than `%10`.

I'd replace the last few lines of your function with:

```
rem = (10 - sum_digits) % 10   # correct computation for the check digit
answer=[]
for i in str(zip_code):
    answer.append(printDigit(int(i)))
answer.append(printDigit(rem))   # add the check digit to the answer!
final='!'+' '.join(answer)+'!'
return final
```

Comment: This produces `!!.!.. .!.!. !!... ...!! .!..! .!!..!` and not `!!.!.. .!.!. !!... ...!! .!..! ...!!!`.

Comment: I get the latter when I try it, so you must be doing something differently than what I've shown. The two lines with comments are the only ones that are different than the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. I noticed that you solved the problem as a C-style programmer. I'm guessing your background is in C/C++. I's like to offer a more Pythonic way:

```
def printBarCode(zip_code):
    digit_dict = {1:'...!!',2:'..!.!',3:'..!!.',4:'.!..!',5:'.!.!.',
                  6:'.!!..',7:'!...!',8:'!..!.',9:'!.!..',0:'!!...'}
    zip_code_list = [int(num) for num in str(zip_code)]
    bar_code = ' '.join([digit_dict[num] for num in zip_code_list])
    check_code = digit_dict[10 - sum(zip_code_list) % 10]
    return '!{} {}!'.format(bar_code, check_code) 

print printBarCode(95014)
```

I used list comprehension to work with each digit rather than to iterate. I could have used the map() function to make it more readable, but list comprehension is more Pythonic. Also, I used the Python 3.x format for string formatting. Here is the output:

```
!!.!.. .!.!. !!... ...!! .!..! ...!!!
>>>
```